# Javascript Regexp only allow `A` or `B` letter only with restriction with one letter

Tags: javascript, regex

I require to allow the user to input either `A` or `B` and length should not exceed 1.

I already tried this, but it does not work:

```
inputValue.replace( /[A|B]/{1}g, '');
```

any suggestion?

Comment: `/[AB]/g` or `/A|B/g`

Comment: Why use `replace`? Please add full relevant code.

Comment: [Don't complicate things](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/). `inputValue == "A" || inputValue == "B"`.

Comment: Yep, `/[A|B]{1}/g` not `/[A|B]/{1}g`

Comment: notice, that `inputValue.replace()` does nothing to the value of `inputValue`.

Comment: [A|B]/g but the solution by Phylogenesis  is probably what you want

Comment: *any suggestion* Yes. (1) Read any regexp tutorial, intro, or documentation. (2) Learn how to use regexp testing sites. (3) Learn how to use the console. (4) Learn how to post questions to SO--"not works" is not a good problem description. (5) Learn basic English spelling; the word "I" is capitalized, as is the first word of sentences.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need a regex for this?

Testing `if(inputValue == 'A' || inputValue == 'B')` seems to be enough.

Anyway, with a regex, it could be something like:

```js
console.log(/^[AB]$/g.test('A'));   // true
console.log(/^[AB]$/g.test('B'));   // true
console.log(/^[AB]$/g.test('AB'));  // false
```

### Update from comment

Using `replace()`, you can remove any character that is not A or B with `[^AB]`. Then, as you only want 1 character, you can take the first one in result with `charAt(0)`:

```js
console.log('abcABC-*/+"@'.replace(/[^AB]/g, '').charAt(0));
```

Comment: If OP insists on a regex then `/^(A|B)$/` or `/^[AB]$/` are more precise.

Comment: But my case they have used the replace method. so i required to replace the input other than `A` and `B`, this is working for me `inputValue.replace(/[C-Z0-9 ]{1}/g, '');` but it allows special characters, how to fix it

Comment: @3gwebtrain If your requirement is to replace characters which are **not** A or B, then write that clearly in your problem description. To do that, read up on basic regexp syntax, especially negated character sets. Stack Overflow is not a tutorial service, as someone with a rep of 4K should know well.

Comment: @3gwebtrain Updated my answer